# PHP time function displays wrong value

Tags: php, mysql

I am using following code

```
list($date, $time) = explode(' ', $row['created_at']);
list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', $date);
list($hour, $minute, $second) = explode(':', $time);
$timemodified = mktime($hour, $minute, $second, $month, $day, $year); 

$threshold = time() - 6;

echo $threshold.'</br>';
echo $timemodified.'</br>';

echo $timemodified - $threshold;
```

It outputs

```
1428631618
1428643990
12372
```

The modified time is just two minutes ago. Why is the difference so big I am just subtracting six seconds. Am I missing sommething?

Comment: where are you extracting $hour,$minute,$second,$month,$day,$year?? and $date, $row['created_at'] also? please give some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `$threshold` time is not really 6 seconds. You can use `strtotime()` function to subtract 6 seconds from your time

```
$newTime = strtotime('-6 seconds', $timemodified);
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $newTime);
```

hope this helps. For my example see this: http://codepad.org/cRp858RG